# Printing addition of char and integer value as float

Tags: c, printing

I'm just wondering why am I getting a 0 value when I try to print the addition of a `char` and an integer value. My code is as follows:

```
int y;
y = 10;

char z;
z = '9';
printf("%f", z + y);
```

Comment: Because `z + y` produces an `int`, not a `float`? Therefore your `printf` call invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: It's up to you to make sure the format string and the arguments match. In your example, the format string calls for a `double`, but the argument is an `int`. So you either need to change the format string, or add a cast to the argument.

Comment: If your compiler warning level is set high enough, you may get a warning about the format not matching the arguments. That would be a good thing to pay attention to.

Answer (score 4):

This call of printf

```
printf("%f", z + y);
```

invokes undefined behavior because you are using the incorrect conversion specifier `%f` with an object of the type int.

You need to cast the argument like for example

```
printf( "%f", ( double )( z + y ) );
```

or

```
printf( "%f", ( float )( z + y ) );
```

though in the last case the argument will be promoted to the type double due to the default argument promotions.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, when you call a function, and you pass the wrong type of argument, C automatically converts it for you.  For example, if I write

```
#include <math.h>

int i = sqrt(144);
printf("%d\n", i);
```

this works, and prints `12`.  It works even though the `sqrt` function actually wants an argument of type `double` — because the compiler knows that, and automatically converts my `int` argument `144` to `double` before passing it to `sqrt`.  (There's also a conversion on the way back, because `sqrt` returns a `double`, which has to be converted back to `int` before assigning to `i`.)

But the `printf` function itself is a big, giant exception to this rule.  In your code, you had

```
printf("%f", z + y);
```

Now, you and I both know that `%f` wants a `double`, but this is not something that, traditionally, the C language can know about.  As far as the C language is concerned, the `printf` function takes one argument of type `const char *` (that is, a string), and then possibly some number of other arguments, depending on the particular `%`-sequences that are found in the format string at run-time.  So the compiler makes only a half-hearted attempt, converting them to a few, common types and then passing them on to `printf` to do the rest.  In your example, since `z` is a `char` and `y` is an `int`, `z + y` will be an `int`, and that's what gets passed to `printf`.  By the time `printf` is chewing on the format string and finds the format specifier `%f`, it has no way of knowing what type of argument was actually passed, so it can't even try to do any conversions of its own.  All it can do is assume that you actually passed a `double` — and, since you didn't, you get a meaningless value printed instead.

Now, although as I've just explained, the compiler didn't traditionally have any license to try to convert `printf` arguments to the proper type, modern compilers typically *do* take a peek at the format string, if they can, and check that things are going to work properly at run time.  For example, when I run your code through one of my compilers, I get `warning: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'int'`.  If your compiler is not giving you warnings like this, you might want to find out if there's a way to enable them, because they're obviously super handy.

Comment: Related: [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57842756/12149471) It also provides some details on how to enable compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in the comments section, it is your responsibility to ensure that the format string and the function arguments match. In your case, they do not match. The result of the expression `z + y` is of type `int`, but you are using the `%f` conversion specifier in the format string, which is only valid for the data types `float` and `double` (`float` [gets promoted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions) to `double`).

As pointed out in the comments section, you have two options to fix this:

1. change the format string to expect an argument of type `int`, or
2. cast the argument to `double` or `float`

The solution using option #1 would look like this:

Change the line

```
printf("%f", z + y);
```

to

```
printf("%d", z + y);
```

The solution using option #2 would look like this:

Change the line

```
printf("%f", z + y);
```

to

```
printf("%f", (double) (z + y) );
```